# Access Denied AWS S3 ObjectList

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

Try to access `listObjectRequest` from a S3 bucket but getting `access denied` Error. Even i have `listObject` permission on my bucket.

I am using `IdentityPool` to access my bucket.

```
ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName+path));
```

Error is

```
Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
```

Let me know which permission is need to call `listObjects` method.

Comment: What makes you think that you should be allowed to access the bucket? Hints: What permissions are associated with the credentials you are using to make the call? What Bucket Policy is on the target bucket? Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: You are not authorised person to use that bucket.

Comment: The correct permission for object listings is `s3:ListBucket`.

Comment: Hi Amrit, was the `IdentityPool` setup by you or by MobileHub? `IdentityPool` has an `unauthenticated` and `authenticated` mode. Can you check which policy has permission to listobjects?